# Office Online Server and SharePoint 2019 Upload Issues

Tags: file-upload, 2019, office-online-server

I have an issue where when my Office Online Server is turned on I cannot upload files larger than 150MB to SharePoint 2019 on premises. The file appears to upload as expected but eventually throws the following error.

[image: Error Message]

I accidently discovered that if I turn off the Office Online Server (I am not talking about stopping the service, but actually shutting down the server) then I am able to upload the file because it uses an entirely different upload approach.

I am at a total loss as to why this is happening.  Up until about a week ago we could upload large files without issue.

Comment: Is your farm patched with the October 2020 PU? If so, this is a known issue.

Comment: Yep, this is correct.  I found it about an hour after posting this.  Thank you!